# LWC: @wire inside method (function)

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, function

I need to run this @wire on a click event.
I thought on creating, inside the LWC class, a method to call it, but it didn't work.

how can I call the WIRE service inside a function with parameter?

something similar to this:

```
    myMethod(PARAMETER){
    @wire(getRelatedMedia, { productId: PARAMETER })
    relatedMedia({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            // this.contacts = data;
            // this.error = undefined;
            console.log(data);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('erro');
            // this.error = error;
            // this.contacts = undefined;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call a wire from within a function. If you wanted to do this, you'd just set the wire parameter.

```
myMethod(PARAMETER){
  this.productId = PARAMETER;
```

...

```
@wire(getRelatedMedia( { productId: '$productId' })
  relatedMedia({data,error}) {
  // code
}
```

Instead, you can use an imparative Apex call:

```
myMethod(PARAMETER){
  getRelatedMedia({productId:PARAMETER})
    .then(data => {
      this.contacts = data;
      this.error = null;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.contacts = null;
      this.error = error;
    });
}
```